# How do I enable DynamoDB Local Logging?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

More than often DynamoDB Local does not show descriptive error messages, in order to see internal errors you need to enable logging.

What are the steps to enable *DynamoDB Local* logging on the standard output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Change to the directory with DynamoDBLocal.jar
2. Create a new file called log4j.properties with the contents:

   log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, stdout

   log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
   log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
   log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=*LOG*%d %p [%c] - %m%n
3. Remove the existing log4j.properties files from the jar (there might be two)

   zip -d DynamoDBLocal.jar log4j.properties

   zip -d DynamoDBLocal.jar log4j.properties
4. Add the new properties file to the jar

   zip -u DynamoDBLocal.jar log4j.properties

Source: https://gist.github.com/mdaley/aaf9b62d90f6817eb72a

Comment: Alas, it doesn't seem to have any effect with dynamodb_local_2015-07-16_1.0.tar.gz

Comment: Also doesn't seem to work with dynamodb_local_2016-05-17.

Comment: Yeah can confirm on dynamodb_local_2016-05-17. Not getting anything logged even though I'm getting errors using dynamo local (And I'm getting `The request processing has failed because of an unknown error` when trying `aws dynamodb list-tables --endpoint-url http://localhost:8000`)

Answer (score 17):

1. Go to the directory that has the DynamoDBLocal.jar
2. Create a file called log4j2.xml with these contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
  <Appenders>
      <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
              <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
      </Console>
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <Logger name="com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.local" level="DEBUG">
        <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
    </Logger>
    <Logger name="com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.local.shared.access.sqlite.SQLiteDBAccess" level="INFO">
      <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
    </Logger>
    <Root level="WARN">
      <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

3. Remove the existing log4j2.xml from the jar

> zip -d DynamoDBLocal.jar log4j2.xml

4. Add the created log4j2.xml to the jar

> zip -u DynamoDBLocal.jar log4j2.xml

**or simply edit the log4j2.xml in the DynamoDBLocal.jar using 7-Zip etc. and overwrite it with the xml above and skip the steps 2-4.**

Comment: this should be the right answer. Only thing I had to fix was some issue with white characters when I copied the content of that xml. Just sanitise it in some file editor.